# Some program or extension to clear project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project

To archive my projects I need to remove all additional files in hand mode - remove bin folder, rsharp data, and many other trash.

Are there any tools or extensions or programs that can do it in automatic mode?

Comment: Do you mean to use "Clean Project"?

Comment: @AndersAbel post your answer and I mark it as answer. Tortoise + Anch it's better way to save a local project examples I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using version control, even for my private projects. TortoiseSVN can be used to set up a local, file based repository. Only code is checked in, when done working on a project the working dir can be deleted and the relevant pieces are in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a batch file (.bat, .cmd, .ps1), or build an exe in C# that does this for you and hook it up as [post build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx).

Comment: Is there no ready-made solutions? I need to write it with my self? ... Sad(